# Error al escribir datos en sensor inercial

Tags: python, python-3.x

He conseguido leer los valores de calibracion del sensor y guardarlos en un archivo.

El problema que tengo es al momento de querer insertar dichos valores al sensor arroja unos errores que no puedo dilucidar por que
Les pongo el script y su ayuda sera de mucha utilidad

```
archivo = open("data.txt","r")

data1= archivo.readline()
data = list(data1.split())  #
print ("longitud de data =", len(data))
print ("tipo de dato =", type(data))
bno.set_calibration(data)
print(" Se a grabado exitosamente la calibracion al BNO055")
archivo.close()
```

El error que me da es

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "menuV3.py", line 168, in <module>
    bno.set_calibration(data)
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 554, in set_calibration
    self._write_bytes(ACCEL_OFFSET_X_LSB_ADDR, data)
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 290, in _write_bytes
    command[4:] = map(lambda x: x & 0xFF, data)
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 290, in <lambda>
    command[4:] = map(lambda x: x & 0xFF, data)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Aca les muestro lo que hace la funcion bno.set_calibration(data)

```
def set_calibration(self, data):
    """Set the sensor's calibration data using a list of 22 bytes that
    represent the sensor offsets and calibration data.  This data should be
    a value that was previously retrieved with get_calibration (and then
    perhaps persisted to disk or other location until needed again).
    """
    # Check that 22 bytes were passed in with calibration data.
    if data is None or len(data) != 22:
        raise ValueError('Expected a list of 22 bytes for calibration data.')
    # Switch to configuration mode, as mentioned in section 3.10.4 of datasheet.
    self._config_mode()
    # Set the 22 bytes of calibration data.
    self._write_bytes(ACCEL_OFFSET_X_LSB_ADDR, data)
    # Go back to normal operation mode.
    self._operation_mode()
```

por ultimo les muestro la funcion write_bytes

```
def _write_byte(self, address, value, ack=True):
    # Write an 8-bit value to the provided register address.  If ack is True
    # then expect an acknowledgement in serial mode, otherwise ignore any
    # acknowledgement (necessary when resetting the device).
    if self._i2c_device is not None:
        # I2C write.
        self._i2c_device.write8(address, value)
    else:
        # Build and send serial register write command.
        command = bytearray(5)
        command[0] = 0xAA  # Start byte
        command[1] = 0x00  # Write
        command[2] = address & 0xFF
        command[3] = 1     # Length (1 byte)
        command[4] = value & 0xFF
        resp = self._serial_send(command, ack=ack)
        # Verify register write succeeded if there was an acknowledgement.
        if ack and resp[0] != 0xEE and resp[1] != 0x01:
            raise RuntimeError('Register write error: 0x{0}'.format(binascii.hexlify(resp)))
```

Comment: Aclaracion los valores de calibracion contenidos en data son bytes y sospecho que mi problema radica en la forma en la que estoy guardandolo al escribir en el archivo

Answer (score 1):

Estás mezclando dos tipos para realizar una operación, por un lado tienes **x** que es una cadena y por otro tienes **0xFF** que es un número, como la operación es un **&**, tienes que parsear a entero el valor de **x**.

Tu función (que no veo en tu código) `map(lambda x: x & 0xFF, data)` debes transformarla a la siguiente:

`map(lambda x: int(x) & 0xFF, data)`

Comment: XBoss muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme

Comment: he realizado el cambio propuesto y lastimosamente tengo otro error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "menuV6.py", line 224, in <module>
    bno.set_calibration(data)
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 554, in set_calibration
    self._write_bytes(ACCEL_OFFSET_X_LSB_ADDR, data)
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 290, in _write_bytes
    command[4:] = map(lambda x: int(x) & 0xFF, data)
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 290, in <lambda>
    command[4:] = map(lambda x: int(x) & 0xFF, data)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[234,'

Comment: disculpa por la falta de pulcritud, no le agarro la mano al formato